# What does "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WILDCARD_TYPE" mean?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I'm trying to access a server with the following code:

```
WebTarget target = client.target(<uri>);
Invocation.Builder builder;
builder = target.request();
builder.header("Authorization", "Token token=<secret>");
builder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response response = builder.buildGet().invoke();
```

I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WILDCARD_TYPE
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MediaTypes.<clinit>    (MediaTypes.java:126)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.<clinit>(OutboundMessageContext.java:88)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:165)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:214)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:59)
at com.peakhosting.pagerduty.Harvester.Harvest.main(Harvest.java:33)
```

From the pom.xml:

From the pom.xml file:

jersey: 0-8-ea
jersey-client :1.19
jersey-client: 2.17
jersey-server:2.17

I didn’t notice the two versions of the jersey-client.  I wonder if that’s the issue.
Can someone please explain what's going on?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Probably a problem with dependencies (missing or versions). Show **all** your depedencies

Comment: But, wouldn't that generate a compile time error.  This is error is a runtime error.

Comment: Why would it be a compile time error, if you are not using that bit of code (which seems to be internal)? Framework code is compiled into .class files (key being _already_ been compiled). It it now known til runtime whether the dependent classes available. If you have ever gotten a NoClassDefFound, you'll have experienced something similar. For instance a compiled class A uses class B. But let's say class B is in a different jar. For some reason jar with class B doesn't get put on classpath. A is already compiled, but during runtime, class B is not on classpath, and causes a NoClassDefFound.

Comment: Similarly, during runtime, an internal class A (that has already been compiled depends on class B (version 1.2). For some reason, we have version 1.0 on the classpath, which doesn't have a method used internally (that is only on version 1.2), we would get a NoSuchMethodError

Comment: Now I don't know if this is the exact problem you are facing, but if you post all your dependencies, I can check.

Comment: From the pom.xml file:

jersey: 0-8-ea
jersey-client :1.19
jersey-client: 2.17
jersey-server:2.17

I didn’t notice the two versions of the jersey-client.  I wonder if that’s the issue.

Comment: **Get rid of** everything not 2.17, and try it. As an aside, if this is not a server side application, you only need the client dependency.